# how many blocks are encrypted at a time in DES Algorithm?

Tags: block-cipher, des

I know that block ciphers encrypts data in the shape of specified blocks and DES also belong to block cipher family. I totally understand the procedure of DES, but I am confused that is DES take all the blocks of 64 bits of any plaint text and apply the process to all of blocks at a time or it encrypts first blocks then 2nd and 3rd and so on.. can anyone explain it Please??

Comment: This depends in the implementation and the mode of operation

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/143790/12) from Security Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Guess what: in counter mode DES doesn't encrypt blocks of plaintext *at all*. In counter (CTR) mode DES encrypts a counter which is XOR-ed with the plaintext.

DES itself doesn't do anything with multiple blocks. DES is an algorithm called a block cipher which handles one block of input and *permutes* it to a block of output. The chosen permutation depends on the key.

To encrypt anything that is not precisely a block with DES (or any other block cipher) you *need* a block cipher [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) . There are many modes of operation in which a block cipher can be configured as underlying *primitive*.

How many bytes are actually encrypted by the mode of operation depends on the mode and implementation. *One instance of DES - the block cipher - will only handle one 64 bit / 8 byte block at a time.*